# Designing Microservice dependencies properly with related data

Tags: dependencies, microservices, composition

This is a highly theoretical question and focuses largely on me not completely grasping design principles behind related data in microservices and responsibility of obtaining related data.

The basic gist of my data could be exampled as follows (each service also hosts data named after the service in a DB which i will hide for simplicity):

I have an API Gateway routing /api/* requests to their proper services and handling authentication.
I have a species-service, the species has a GUID PK and a name.
I have a zoo-service, the zoo has a GUID PK and a name.
I have an animal-service, an animal has a GUID PK, a species FK and a zoo FK and a name.

Following scenarios have to happen:

1. I want to retrieve all animals in a zoo.
2. I want to retrieve all animals of a species.
3. I want to retrieve a single animal.

This is my current implementation (which I think may be flawed):

1. The API Gateway recieves a GET request to /api/zoo/{zooId}/animals and requests the zoo-service to compose the data. The zoo-service requests all animals, grabs their species ID's and sorts them by species. If the species service does not respond they are only sorted by species ID's, but the species has no name.
2. The API Gateway recieves a GET request to /api/species/{speciesID}/animals and requests the species service to compose the data. The species-service requests all animals and displays returns them.
3. The API Gateway recieves a GET request to /api/animal/{animalID} and requests the animal-service to retrieve an animal. The returned data only contains the zoo ID and species ID.

I have the following two questions:

1. In the given example, does the dependency of microservices seem reasonable? I am trying to handle a non-responsive service as good as possible in the service that depends on it.
2. In the third scenario, who would be responsible for retrieving the data of an animals species and zoo? (I'd guess you would want as exact relevant data as possible for the entity you are requesting, so delivering the zoo name and species name would be good) The Frontend, API Gateway or the animal-service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This decomposition looks like taking a relational DB schema and assigning each table to a different microservice.  This decomposition takes all the coupling of a monolith and combines it with all the complexity of microservices, which means that you get very few of the benefits of either.

An alternative decomposition focuses on the functionality: what operations are being exposed and how are they related (and what sort of consistency/independence relations should hold between the operations).  If there's a strong consistency requirement between two operations, that's a strong sign that those two operations belong in the same microservice (doing that doesn't guarantee consistency, but not doing that dramatically increases the effort of ensuring consistency without giving the benefits of separate microservices (beyond, perhaps, having the ability to say "we have more microservices than we need!", if that's the sort of thing that gives one satisfaction)).

So assuming we have an "add animal A with species S to zoo Z" operation, the question is then whether we want a guarantee that any subsequent request for all the animals in Z, all the animals of S, or the specific animal A sees the result of that operation.  If the answer is yes, then those four operations probably "want" to be in the same microservice and the implementations of those operations are going to be coupled as a consequence.  If the answer is no, then it's likely that eventual consistency with some liveness guarantee is acceptable, in which case (barring the presence of some other consistency relationship) put the operations into separate microservices and patterns like CQRS are possible.

If doing CQRS, the service providing the "get all animals in the zoo" operation could then have its own view of what animals there are and their respective species.  It then doesn't depend on the animals/species services being available: those being down/unable to talk to this service (which could happen because one service changed something, it should be noted) simply means that the view is out of date.  Eventually, communication will be re-established and the operation will return updated data.

Comment: Okay, so I'll look into CQRS and check how feasible it is to implement. I am fairly new to microservices and breaking down a monolith, which got me into that position.

I'd guess breaking down a monolith without much knowledge would result in monolithic patterns.

Given that, would implementing the API composition pattern be a valid first step?
Also would the service composing/storing the view only handle one view or multiple views?

Comment: You could have one service/component implement arbitrarily many of the views.

Answer (score 1):

> In the given example, does the dependency of microservices seem
> reasonable?

```
GET /api/zoos/{zooId}/animals
```

The first endpoint exposes a resource called *zoos*. A zoo with ID *zooId* can be selected. And a zoo contains a resource called *animals*.

```
GET /api/animals/{animalID}
```

The second endpoint exposes a resource called anmials. An animal with ID *animalId* can be selected.

Let's imagine for a second that each animal in the /zoos/{zooId}/animals resource contains an ID. You want consumers to be able to select an animal by ID from the animals resource for a given zoo. What path would you expose? Naturally:

```
GET /api/zoos/{zooId}/animals/{animalId}
```

I think this is the first clue to the composition. Is the animal returned by the zoos service the same animal as the one returned by the animals service?

Put another way, would we expect the data returned by

```
GET /api/zoos/{zooId}/animals/{animalId}
```

and the data returned by

```
GET /api/animals/{animalID}
```

to be the exact same?

Even though they may both represent the same animal, the animal in the zoos service is fundamentally a separate entity to the animal in the animals service. In fact I would not even expect them to share the same *animalId*. The *animalId* from the zoos service should identify an animal only within a given zoo only.

Put another way, why would we expect a zoo to use the same identifier for an animal as the one that identifies the animal in the animals service? If two models from two services share the same identifier, then they are basically the same "service", and we are no longer doing microservices.

When we also consider the third endpoint:

```
GET /api/species/{speciesID}/animals
```

It looks like we have another service also exposing an *animals* resource, which you could also put a /{animalId} path segment on the end to return an animal by ID.

Imagine what an actual request and response pair might look like to satisfy each of your required scenarios:

> I want to retrieve all animals in a zoo.

Request:

```
GET /api/zoos/london-regents-park/animals
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "animalId": 11111, // this is the zoos unique identifier for this animal
    "id": "london-regents-park", 
    "animalName": "Sam",
    "species": "Troglodytes gorilla", // scientific name
    "animalExternalId": "GORI038974", // Optional, the global identifier for an animal if one exists
  },
  ...
]
```

> I want to retrieve all animals of a species.

Request:

```
GET /api/species/troglodytes-gorilla-beringei/animals
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "animalId": "73a90acaae2b1ccc0e969709665bc62f", // the id of the animal in the species service only
    "id": "troglodytes-gorilla-beringei", 
    "location": "London Zoo, Regent's park", // the location of this animal
    "globalAnimalIdentifier": "GORI038974", // Optional, the global identifier for an animal if one exists
  },
  ...
]
```

> I want to retrieve a single animal.

Request:

```
GET /api/animal/GORI038974
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": "GORI038974", // the global id of this animal
  "name": "Sam the Gorilla",
  "zoo": "London, regents park",
  "species": "Troglodytes gorilla beringei" // actual scientific name
}
```

This is what we would expect from having 3 separate services. We get the data we want, but we cannot expect the data returned from our services to be relationally consistent. This system does not have a relational data model, it has 3 separate relational data models.

> An animal as an entity depends on the zoo and the species existing

Not in the animals service model, or to clarify, only to the extent that the animal model has zoo and species properties. The dependency here is implied rather than enforced.

> Given this introduces the issue of synchronizing logically independent data (the species name in the known animals of a zoo, for example)

This is always going to be the case when using microservices. For example, consider the use case that we want to add a new animal to a zoo? We might decide that because we have 3 services then we need to have 3 distinct updates but that is only the case if we actually care about all 3 scenarios equally.

Maybe scenario 1 is real time and scenarios 2 and 3 are run once per week. Then we might only want to update the zoos service in real time, and have some kind of offline process synchronising data to the others.

In some other use cases it may be perfectly acceptable to have animals in the zoos service which do not exist in the other services. It all depends on how users will use our services.

> It also introduces an issue of redundancy

One of the main reasons for using microservices is to reduce coupling in your system or architecture. Redundancy (or, the duplication of data) is quite literally the only way that reducing coupling makes sense in microservices.

Comment: While I understand your point, I may need to clarify a bit more.

An animal as an entity depends on the zoo and the species existing. A zoo and a species does (logically) not depend on an individual animal existing nor on each other (zoo<->species) existing. 

Given this introduces the issue of synchronizing logically independent data (the species name in the known animals of a zoo, for example). It also introduces an issue of redundancy.

Comment: @AndyTroschke I have responded inline in the answer